# Lex coding with C

Tags: c, text, lex

I want to get and print text within double quotes with using Lex.

```
["]?([A-Z]*[a-z]*[0-9]*)*["]? {
printf("STR(%s ),yytext");
return 1;
}
```

I used this but something wrong that I can't figure it out.

Example:

Input

```
"CNG230 ASN1 Average"
```

Output

```
STR("CNG230 ASN1 Average")
```

Example 2:

Input

```
 "CNG230/492 Global average"
```

Output

```
 STR("CNG230/492 Global average")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually say what is wrong with either of your examples, and I am assuming that

```
printf("STR(%s ),yytext");
```

is just a typo for

```
printf("STR(%s )",yytext);
```

but there are two problems that I can see.

1. If you've specified your problem correctly, you don't care what's inside the quotes as long as it isn't another quote. So your rule reduces to

   ```
   \"[^"]*\" { ... }
   ```
2. The default action if no rules match is to echo the input. So you need another rule to consume everything that doesn't match this rule. Place this afterwards:

   ```
   .|\n {}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem seems to be that your pattern doesn't allow space as a valid character.  You also don't need to be quite so complex with your matching:

```
["]?[A-Za-z0-9 ]*["]? {
    printf("STR(%s)\n", yytext);
    return 1;
}
```

Note that I've also provided `printf()` with a value to print, and output a newline at the end so you'll see the information in a timely manner.

Comment: It is a good aproach thanks for that but after appyling this code I got errors that says line numbers and rule cannot be matched also there is another example that contains characters like /. So, what can you say about that the below part is ok but need to understand how to create ["]?[A-Za-z0-9 ]*["]? in a correct way? Thanks.

Comment: I can't possibly debug what you've not shown.  Taken on its own (prefixed by `%%` and followed with `%%`), that fragment can be compiled into a free-standing program, and when I type `"abc def"` at it, it responds with `STR("abc def")`.  All that matches what you asked about.  Without seeing more of your scanner, no-one can tell you what's wrong with the rest of the code.

Comment: I managed to do that but it is like STR("C) STR(N) ... How can I possibly do in STR("CNG230 ASN1 Average") format?